# How can I gift an app in the app store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I want to gift an OS X app, specifically OS X Mountain Lion to my mother in-law. How do I achieve this from the OS X App Store? I can't find any gifting option for both apps I own and apps I do not own.

Comment: If and when the Mac app store gets gifting, flag this for re-opening and we can use it to denote when things change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to gift Mac App Store apps directly. There is a workaround where you could buy an iTunes Gift card (from the iTunes store home menu) for exactly the price of the app and the recipient can redeem the code in the Mac App Store
[image]

Comment: This does not appear for me on OS X apps. I am using the "App Store" application.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer above

Comment: After trying to find the link you have provided in the "App Store" I finally realised you must have tried to do this through iTunes. In future please post instructions instead of just a screen shot that's out of context. Visit the "iTunes" store from within iTunes, click the "Home" button if not already there, near the right there is a banner depicting the options presented above in @bluewoodtree's answer.

Comment: I've closed this, but in the interest of learning - the best thing to do is to edit out all the wrong information and just leave the good information. Anyone that cares will learn / know to [look over the edit history](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/88077/revisions) - and it won't confuse people 6 months from know wondering why an answer has a mix of wrong and right information. Focus on the long term pay-off, and not the process by which the correct answer was forged.